# AMPscript IndexOf / If Product Included in list

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, code

I'd like to display a bulleted list of available products (i.e. Prod1, Prod2, Prod3) based on a list of already-purchased products stored in "Product List" column. I've gotten far enough to think that IndexOf is the right function, but I'm looking for some guidance about how to structure the AMPscript to output a list based on already purchase products.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the BuildRowsetFromString function that is outlined in the following [documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#BuildRowSetFromString)

This allows you to pass in a string and specify what the delimiter is, an example of what this string would look like would be. Ex: product1;product2;product3

```
%%[
  set @productrowset = BuildRowsetFromString(@Product_List,";")

  for @cnt_product = 1 to RowCount(@productrowset) do
  set @record_product = Field(Row(@productrowset,@cnt_product),1)
]%%
  <li>%%=v(@record_product)=%%</li>
  %%[next @cnt_product]%%
```

Output:

- Product1
- Product2
- Product3